# How to prevent browser increasing font size on browser zoom?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been using media queries to adjust font-size fine on mobile devices however when I zoom in/out using each browsers individual zoom features the font size on various elements increases. I've set overflow to off in the various elements however it doesn't look too pleasant on zoom out.

On StackOverflow for example, when I zoom out all font sizes/elements do not increase in size - is there a way I can apply this to my own pages, I've tried "  font-size-adjust: none" and "text-size-adjust: none" with no luck.

Edit - For some reason this only occurs on Chrome. The other browsers do not increase the font size.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try setting the `body { 
    font-size-adjust: 0.58;
}` It would set the aspect size to 0.58 irrespective of the Font family

Comment: @Abolarinstephen - Thanks, seems to help with other browsers but not Chrome :{

Comment: Try `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;`